# IntelliJ: Spacig of caret when writing XML (Spring Beans)

Tags: intellij-idea

When I am writing for example Spring Bean I often have empty element without children only with attributes.

Default way that IDEA provides spacing is the first one on the picture (with arrow), which I dont like. I prefer the second one, which can I only alter manually. How can I set up IDEA to do so automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Enter *File* -> *Settings* (or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)
- Browse to *Code style* -> *XML*
- Click on *Other* tab. Uncheck ***Align attributes*** checkbox